# Python, regression, decision trees

Tags: python, regression

I apologize in advance for my English but it is not my native language. For this reason, it seems difficult for me to solve the problem that is bothering me.

I'll go straight to the clarification. I create a semester "project" for studies in which learning through regression takes place. I built the database myself thanks to the scrapy library and information from metacritic.com

This is what the database header looks like.

(https://i.ibb.co/p2pk2bd/stack1.png)

After visual operations (graphs, histograms, etc.) and operations that changed value types, the database looks as follows:

(https://i.ibb.co/J2Gn0Ms/stack2.png)

vectors were created using the method:

```
A = LabelBinarizer (). Fit_transform (games.Publisher)
for i in range (len (games.Publisher)):
games.at [i, 'Publisher'] = A [i]
```

The column value types are as follows:

(https://i.ibb.co/q9vMVK1/stack3.png)

I divide the set into X and y.

```
X = games.drop(['Name','Metascore','Desc','Release Date','Userscore'], axis=1)
y = games['Metascore']
```

X:

(https://i.ibb.co/VJ0LZfG/stack4.png)

y:

(https://i.ibb.co/Qvsw9JT/stack5.png)

Using the function:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 1)
```

I divide the set into subsets.

The problem arises at the time of regression (the decision tree method is required here).

(https://i.ibb.co/bL8Xyhz/stack6.png)

If only someone so kind and helped me tame this mistake <3

Answer (score 1):

Either it is a simple one or I misunderstand you:

Under 'developer' and other columns you have arrays. Why?
This is the reason for the exception. This is also explained by the error message by the way.

Replace every array with a 0 or a placeholder or an actual value and it should work.
If the values in the array are important you should make a full line for every of that arrays.

Comment: But how can I write a function that would automate it for me?

Comment: do you need the information inside? to me it seems that it is filled with zeros?

Comment: but I think it makes sense to open a new question with that issue because this is more of a pandas issue unlike your data science question here. And please add real code or data not just the screenshots. this makes it easier.